# I'm trying to implement infinite scrolling into my UITableViewController and unsure how to use the database results returned

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios7, uiscrollview

Currently trying to implement infinite scrolling into my app using this plugin: https://github.com/pronebird/UIScrollView-InfiniteScroll

**So far I've added this code to my tableview controller viewDidAppear and viewDidDisappear methods:**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // setup infinite scroll
    // keep a weak reference to table view
    __weak UITableView *weakTableView = self.tableView;

    [self.tableView addInfiniteScrollWithHandler:^{
        // keep a strong reference to table view
        __strong UITableView *strongTableView = weakTableView;

        // seems like our table view didn't make it
        if(strongTableView == nil) return;


        //
        // fetch your data here, can be async operation,
        // just make sure to call finishInfiniteScroll in the end


        // finish infinite scroll animation
        [strongTableView finishInfiniteScroll];
    }];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    // remove infinite scroll
    [self.tableView removeInfiniteScroll];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

I drag the table and the spinner shows underneath the last row and disappears after a second or two. Now all I need to do is get the data from my array and add it to block in the viewDidAppear code.

**This is how I currently get my parse.com data into an NSMuteableArray instance named "people":**

```
- (void)populatePeopleArrayWithCloudData {
    // Grab data for datasource and store in people array
    NSLog(@"view did load");
    people = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"People"];
    [query whereKey:@"active" equalTo:@1];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query setLimit:10];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {

                Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
                [person setName:[object objectForKey:@"name"]];
                [person setNotes:[object objectForKey:@"notes"]];
                [person setAge:[[object objectForKey:@"age"] intValue]];
                [person setSince:[object objectForKey:@"since"]];
                [person setFrom:[object objectForKey:@"from"]];
                [person setReferenceNumber:[object objectForKey:@"referenceNumber"]];

                PFFile *userImageFile = object[@"image"];
                [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                        [person setImage:image];
                    }
                }];

                [person setActive:[[object objectForKey:@"active"] intValue]];
                [person setObjectId:[object objectId]];
                [people addObject:person];
            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }

        NSLog(@"Calling reloadData on %@ in viewDidLoad", self.tableView);
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }];

}
```

I limit results to 10. Now what I wish to do is keep grabbing the next 10 results that haven't already been grabbed every time I scroll to the bottom of the table. This code that helps me do this needs to go in the block mentioned above.

**The "people" instance is used by my tableviewdatasource methods:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[self tableView] dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

        // Configure the cell...

        Person *current;
        if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView]) {
            current = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        } else {
            current = [people objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        }

        [[cell textLabel] setText: [current name]];
        [[cell imageView] setImage: [current image]];
        [[cell detailTextLabel] setText: [current notes]];

    return cell;
}
```

How do I use my database results with this plugin? As you can see I limit results to 10 and I need to grab the next 10 when I've scrolled to the bottom of the table and add them after the last row in the table.

Kind regards

**UPDATE - my numbers of rows in section method as it stands:**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.


    if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView]) {
        return [searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [people count];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy to help, but you should probably give it a shot first for us to provide feedback. A few thoughts to get you going...

The general idea is to use the "skip" property on PFQuery to get the next 10. Each time you call it, you add 10.

So create your query as you do, keep it around in a property, but move your findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock call to your infiniteScrollHandler,  adding 10 to skip each time after you call it. Then at the end of the handling (where you call table reload now), call [strongTableView finishInfiniteScroll]

In your numberOfRows, you'll have to provide the maximum number of people available at your source.

Comment: I've tried to think how to put this together and it's doing my head in slightly :). Firstly I've created a capturedQuery instance variable of PFQuery type. I will use this to capture the query before the block is run.

Comment: I do note that you'll have two levels of "block-age" (a block within a block). Probably best to first use findObjects: and then worry about doing the search in the background.